# Создание нескольких террайнов в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Для чего нужно несколько террейнов ? короче говоря оптимизировать игру, при входе в триггер что бы террейн включался а если вышел то выключался что бы не грузить всю игру.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но тут проблема одна выяснилась, при рисований на одном террейне всё повторяется и для остальных и они получаются идентичны...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопросы такие:

> Хорошая ли идея с несколькими террейнами ?
>
> Как решить проблему с рисованием ?

Comment: Как решить проблему с рисованием ? Не клонировать, а создать новый террейн

Comment: +10 к ауре за ответ

Comment: а как вам идея с несколькими терреинами ?

Comment: Нормально, но на стыках костыли делать придется, как коллайдеров, так и швов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы  разделить террейны, для каждого нужно использовать свои данные `TerrainData`.

В любом случае создание нескольких террейнов задача непростая: стыковка вершин, смешивание текстур, не говорю уже про лайтмапы. Штатные средства Unity не позволяют делать их объединение и совместно редактировать. Советую посмотреть в сторону `AssetStore`, там присутствует большое количество плагинов для создания больших поверхностей, что нибудь наподобие `TerrainComposer` или `MapMagic World`.